# In the children's show Toopy and Binoo, is Binoo a boy or a girl?

Tags: character, toopy-and-binoo

Help me settle a debate with my 5-year-old daughter.

In the children's show [*Toopy and Binoo*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0459161/reference/), is Binoo a boy or a girl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Treehouse TV refers](http://toopyandbinoo-season1and2.treehousetv.com/universe.html) to both characters as 'he'.

> Toopy is a mouse with a vivid imagination. **He** transforms reality into a series of fantastic stories brimming with amazing creatures.
>
> Binoo, the tiny cat, is Toopy’s ideal companion. **He** shares in the adventures with absolute wonder and untainted innocence, often outdoing Toopy in imagination.

Comment: Yah...He is definitely male.

Comment: lol, thanks now I can end a long standing argument with a 5 year old.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear answer to that. Ive researched it myself and even the original french characters are never defined as male or female. Toopy most often comes across as a male, but in more than one episode has dressed up as a girl and talked about kissing princes or being beautiful in dresses etc. The voice is a male for sure, but as far as I can tell, the actual orientation of the character is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There are a considerable number of licenced *Toopy and Binoo* books available. Toopy and Binoo are both consistently described with he/him pronouns, indicating that they identify as male.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Toopy & Binoo - Funny Halloween](https://archive.org/details/funnyhalloween0000joli/page/n11/mode/2up)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure they're both boys (Toopy refers to Binoo as he in some episodes) but Toopy does "girl" things like dressing up like a princess so the show is for girls and boys.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.

Answer (score -2):

Toopy and Binoo are both male but are not subject to gender specific roles.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you could flesh this answer out with some sources, indicating *why* you believe you're correct, this could be a good answer. Until then, it's just conjecture.